# Why don't render css property in webform of master page?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, master-pages, webforms, content-pages

I'm using asp.net in VS 2012. I create a master page and design into it main section and using CSS and JS in it. Now i add a content page. But i have a problem:
--Why can't i see my css effects in content page?
the master page name is "amood.master" and the content page is "aboutUS.aspx".
For more explain:"I see css effects in master page but when using acontent page,all of css effect are disable!!! WHY? "
Source code of web form:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/amood.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm3.aspx.cs" Inherits="newMetroDesign.WebForm3" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

this is master page code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="amood.master.cs" Inherits="newMetroDesign.amood" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">

         <link href="CSS/Stylesss.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/dw_tooltip_c.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="css/ex.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        dw_Tooltip.defaultProps = {
            //supportTouch: true, // set false by default
            wrapFn: dw_Tooltip.wrapTextByImage
        }


        dw_Tooltip.content_vars = {
            L2: {
                caption: 'برنامه نويس', // optional caption 


                txt: 'مهدي تحصيلداري<br/>و پايگاه داده  C#.NET برنامه نويس<br/>m.tahsildari@gmail.com',
                w: 200
            },
            L3: {
                caption: 'طراح سايت', // optional caption 

                txt: 'حميد طالبي<BR/>طراح و برنامه نويس سايت<BR/>mr.talebihamid@hotmail.com',
                w: 200
            }
        }


    </script>

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="MASTERheader">
            <div id="masterlogocontainer">
                <ul>
                    <li class="logo">
                        <a class="headMenu ">
                            <div class="masterlogop"></div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <img src="IMAGES/sadlogo.png" alt="logo" width="80" height="80" />

                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="masternav">
                <ul>
                    <li >
                        <a href="#">
                        <img src="IMAGES/Telephone.png" /><br />

                        <span>تماس با ما</span>
                             </a>
                    </li>
                    <li >
                        <img src="IMAGES/About.png" /><br />
                        <a href="aboutus.aspx"></a>
                        <span>درباره ما</span>
                    </li>
                    <li >     
                        <a href="default.aspx">
                        <img src="IMAGES/Brush.png" />
                        <span> طراحی</span>

                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li  >
                         <a href="default.aspx">
                        <img src="IMAGES/Market.png" /><br />

                        <span>محصولات</span>
                         </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div style="height:50px;"></div>

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <div id="mastercontent">

        </div>
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <a id="return" href="default.aspx">
            <div class="btnreturn">
                بازگشت
            </div>
        </a>
        <%--************************ FOOTER *****************************--%>

     <div id="masterfooter">
            <p>گروه طراحان ساد</p>

            <p>     آدرس دفتر مرکزي : مشهد – خيابان احمدآباد – رضا 16  - پلاک 67 </p>
            <p>All Rights Reserved For SAAD Co.  &nbsp; &copy; 2013</p>
                <p>  <a class="showTip L3 colour" href="#"> طراحي</a> و <a class="showTip L2 colour" href="#"> برنامه نويسي </a></p>

        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: master page without web form]

[image: master page with web form]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible reason is that CSS start referencing the path in case of each page relative to itself. So you have to make sure , your master page as well as pages should follow the same relative structure . Example

```
           mysite.css
           Master.master
           MyPage.aspx
```

Other way

```
          mysite.css
          Shared/Master.master
          Admin/MyPage.aspx
```